# How to display image blob for react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-storage

I try to show image in my react-native app. I've uploaded photo into 
 my Firebase Storage and it's work. Then i try to display my image from Firebase Storage, but the file is blob. I want to convert blob to image but i don't know the syntax. Might be one of you could help me to solve this.

where should i place RNFetch blob? I've tried to place inside componentWillMount and it show error.

```
uploadImage(uri, mime = 'application/octet-stream') {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const uploadUri = uri
            let uploadBlob = null

            const imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profileImg').child(`${this.state.user.uid}/Profile Image - ${this.state.user.uid}`)

            fs.readFile(uploadUri, 'base64')
            .then((data) => {
                return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` })
            })
            .then((blob) => {
                uploadBlob = blob
                return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime })
            })
            .then(() => {
                uploadBlob.close()
                return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
            })
            .then((url) => {
                console.log(url)
                resolve(url)
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e)
                reject(e)
            })
        })
    }

    getProfileImage(){
        let options = {
        title: 'Choose Photo',
        storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images'
      }
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);

          if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
          }
          else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
          }
          else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
          }
          else {
            let image_uri = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
            this.uploadImage(response.uri)
            .then((url) => { 
                console.log('uploaded')
                this.setState({
                    image_uri: url,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
            firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
                photoURL: this.state.image_uri
            });
          }
      })
    }
```

Comment: probably using a data uri - have you looked at Blob documentation at all? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: i don't really understand about the link that you give. i have looked at this link actually https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob. But i don't know where should i place RN fetch blob.

Comment: when I posted the comment you had no code in the question, so it was a broad suggestion

Comment: yeah, i forgot to post the code in the question.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem and the workaround that i implented was to put the file type in the State

in Constructor

```
constructor() {
    super();
    // we will change it to fill the image file type from response
    this.state = {
        fileType: ""
    };
}
```

and in the getImage() function we should change state to put the file type

```
getImage() {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
        console.log("Response = ", response);
        this.setState({
            fileType: response.type
        });
......... the rest of the code
```

and in uploadImage() you should put the mime to the fileType in state as implemented here

```
 uploadImage(uri, mime = this.state.fileType) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const uploadUri =
            Platform.OS === "ios" ? uri.replace("file://", "") : uri;
        let uploadBlob = null;

        const imageRef = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref("images/")
            .child(Date.now());

        fs.readFile(uploadUri, "base64")
            .then(data => {
                return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
            })
            .then(blob => {
                uploadBlob = blob;
                var metadata = {
                    contentType: mime
                };

                return imageRef.put(uri, metadata);
            })
            .then(() => {
                uploadBlob.close();
                return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
            })
            .then(url => {
                resolve(url);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

this is my first answer BTW

Answer (score 0):

This works for my case:

`userPhoto` is is a blob string.

```
  <img className="pic__photo" src={"data:image/png;base64," + userPhoto} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, what you're trying to do is upload image to **firebase** by converting `base64` to `blob` and getting the `blob` from *success query* and convert to `base64` to display it again.

Since you're already using a promise, what you can do is check if the image has been **uploaded successfully**, then display the same `base64` otherwise your `original data`.

```
// Default Image data
let image_uri = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

this.uploadImage(response.uri)
            .then((url) => { 
                // Success, replace with base64 you've got
                console.log('uploaded')
                this.setState({
                    image_uri
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
               this.setState({
                    image_uri: // SOME DEFAULT IMAGE VALUE
                });
            })
```